# Printing multiple lines in a text box/block .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

So what I'm trying to do is print outputs to a textbox but what's happening is it's always using the last textbox2.text it finds because I assume that each time I print it out it overrides the last output. I'm looking for some sort of work around

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ProgrammingProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btn_getinfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string UserInput = "76561198056932916";
           // string UserInput = textBox.Text;
            ProfileSummary(UserInput);
        }

        public void ProfileSummary(string SteamID)
        {
            string SteamKey = "CensoredAPIKEY";
            WebClient c = new WebClient(); 
            var data = c.DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/" + "?key=" + SteamKey + "&steamids=" + SteamID);
            //Console.WriteLine(data);
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
            JArray players = (JArray)o["response"]["players"];

            if (players.Count > 0)
            {
                int PrivacyLevel = (int)players[0]["communityvisibilitystate"];
                string username = (string)players[0]["personaname"];
                string ProUrl = (string)players[0]["profileurl"];
                double LastLogOff = (double)players[0]["lastlogoff"];
                int CurrentStatus = (int)players[0]["personastate"];
                int GamePlaying = (int)players[0]["gameid"];

                textBox2.Text = "your username is " + username + "\n";
                textBox2.Text = "You last logged off on " + ConvertUnix(LastLogOff) + "\n";

                if (PrivacyLevel == 3)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = "This user's account is public"; 
                }
                else if (PrivacyLevel == 1)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = "This user's account is private";
                }
                switch (CurrentStatus)
                {
                    case 1:
                        textBox2.Text = "This user is offline";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        textBox2.Text = "This User is online and playing";
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = "You have entered the SteamID incorrectly";
            }

        Console.ReadLine();  // Don't remove you idiot

    }

    public static DateTime ConvertUnix(double unixTimeStamp)
    {
        // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Local);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
}
```

the output of this code will be the last textbox2.text so in this case it would be the switch statement. I know I haven't explained it the best but I just don't know why this is happening, Thanks

Comment: Are you just looking for how to concatenate?  A simple (not necessarily optimized) way would be:  `textBox2.Text += "This user is offline";`

Comment: What is the output your getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `textBox2.Text += "more text to be added to the text box"` instead of `textBox2.Text = "more text to be added to the text box"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that by using `textBox2.Text =`, you're overwriting the value. Instead, if you want to add lines, use `textBox2.Text += "myString";`. This will *append* the string to the textbox instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 3):

you should use += operator after first equal.

```
            textBox2.Text = "your username is " + username + "\n";
            textBox2.Text += "You last logged off on " + ConvertUnix(LastLogOff) + "\n";

            if (PrivacyLevel == 3)
            {
                textBox2.Text += "This user's account is public"; 
            }
            else if (PrivacyLevel == 1)
            {
                textBox2.Text += "This user's account is private";
            }


            switch (CurrentStatus)
            {
                case 1:
                    textBox2.Text += "This user is offline";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textBox2.Text += "This User is online and playing";
                    break;

            }
        }

        else
        {
            textBox2.Text += "You have entered the SteamID incorrectly";

        }
```

Comment: Man the things you learn thanks so much and have fun answering peoples questions on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

the answer is as they describe above but I would like to suggest that you use a 
richtextbox since you have more than one message and it would be better if you display them in Separate lines to do so

```
richtextbox1.text="\r\n"+some string;
```

the "\r\n" is to go to new line and then insert the text in that new line
.